# Android/Chrome jQuery AJAX Request fails with parsererror before getting to server

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have a web app with lots of jQuery AJAX requests that work on all platforms except Android (Chrome v 50).  I'm using jQuery 2.1.4

Here's the code:

```
var createRequest = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/item/?',
    data: {
        u_id: uid, 
        title: title,
        text: text,
    }
});

createRequest.done(function(response){
    console.log('DONE');
    console.log(response);
});

createRequest.fail(function(response){
    console.log('FAIL');
    console.log(response);

});
```

When I trigger the createRequest, I get a 200 response in the network console, but the request fails, and in fact never gets to the server at all.  The response sent to .fail is an xhr object with statusText "parsererror".

In the console:

```
FAIL
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "parsererror"}
```

No matter what I try (including dataType: 'json', dataType: 'text', JSON stringifying the data before sending, adding a full url with http:// instead of a relative url), I can't get the $.ajax call to get past the parsererror and actually send data to the server.

This works perfectly well on all desktop browsers and iOS Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same error even if I try to do a simple $.ajax GET request to a different endpoint.  The request fails with a parsererror without ever hitting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem was the ? at the end of the url without a parameter.  The request was being constructed as

```
http://www.example.com/api/item/?&uid=1234&title=Test&text=test
```

It was the **/?&** that was the problem

Adding a parameter to the initial URL definition fixes the problem:

```
var createRequest = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/item?u_id=' + uid,
    data: { 
        title: title,
        text: text
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me know if you need a new token.

Answer (score 0):

The last comma after text: text, throws it off. Should be:

```js
var createRequest = $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/api/item/?',
data: {
    u_id: uid, 
    title: title,
    text: text
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex.  I've tried removing the trailing commas and I get the same result.  Fails with a parsererror.

Comment: In fact, even when I remove the data attribute completely, the request never gets to the server.  It just fails immediately.